# UI not updating until function call is complete

Tags: javascript, html

```
 function handleCellClick(clickedCellEvent) {
    
      const clickedCell = clickedCellEvent.target;
      const clickedCellIndex = parseInt(clickedCell.getAttribute('data-cell-index'));
   
      clickedCell.innerHTML = currentMarker;
    
      ComputersMove();
    }
```

Can someone tell me why `clickedCell.innerHTML = currentMarker` does not update the UI when it is read but instead waits until `ComputersMove()` is finished to update the UI? `ComputersMove()` is a costly function that can take a couple of seconds to finish executing.

Are there any ways around this? not sure if workers are the correct way to go?

Comment: can you rewrite ComputersMove so that it is done in a web worker? maybe even `setTimeout(ComputersMove)` would make a difference - but a costly function will always be costly unless it is written to not be costly

Comment: Why can’t you put ComputersMove() on a thread or async?

Comment: by itself, making ComputersMove async won't do a thing @RussJ

Comment: Are you sure `clickedCell.innerHTML = currentMarker` this part is working? Try removing the `ComputersMove()` function and see what the result is.

Comment: Read the question @HymnZzy - OP states that the UI updates

Comment: @Bravo I am currently making an AI to play tictactoe using Monte Carlo Tree Search.  I have never used web workers before but I assume I can pass objects from the main thread to the worker and back?

Comment: @Bravo .. from the above code, can you figure out where the `currentMarker` value is coming from and what's there in `CompuetrsMove()` . Please don't assume I have not read the question.

Comment: @HymnZzy I do state that the UI updates after the function call has executed.

Comment: Sarah. My question is if the UI update is actually happening `clickedCell.innerHTML = currentMarker` at this point or if there is some other line of code inside `ComputersMove()` that's updating it. From the snippet you have provided it looks like the latter case for me. Best way to check it is put an alert or console log to see what the value of `currentMarker` is before `ComputersMove()` is executed.

Comment: @HymnZzy - it's the `clickedCell.innerHTML = currentMarker;` that isn't updating until after `ComputersMove()` finishes ... it's quite common in browsers that intensive computation prevents UI refresh from occuring in a timely fashion

Comment: @Bravo .. there is a single line solution to fix that but will wait till sarah confirms what's coming in the alert/console

Comment: if there's a single line solution ... why do you think the UI is updated in ComputersMove? also, an alert will change the behaviour of the code significantly

Comment: @Bravo Because I don't see where the `currentMarker` value is coming from. I have a reason to believe the value of `currentMarker` in the above code is not the updated value. I know alert and console changes the behaviour of the code and that's why I first asked to disable the `ComputersMove` function and see the what happens. before you claimed I have not read the question.

Comment: but if the code does `clickedCell.innerHTML = currentMarker;` and THEN updates the value of `currentMarker` inside `ComputersMove`, that won't change `clickedCell.innerHTML` - you're overthinking a very common issue

Comment: @Bravo .. how certain are you that there's no line of code in `ComputersMove()` that's impacting `clickedCell.innerHTML` and `currentMarker` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225021/discussion-between-hymnzzy-and-bravo).